# Modify Appxmanifest - Add Element to XML via Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, xml-parsing, appx, appxmanifest

Right now I'm working on a Azure DevOps Building Pipeline and got stuck at manipulating the generated Package.appxmanifest in a way I need it.

**What I have:**

```
<Package>
  <Capabilities>
    <uap2:Capability Name="spatialPerception" />
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

**What I need:**

```
<Package>
  <Capabilities>
    <uap2:Capability Name="spatialPerception" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="perceptionSensorsExperimental" />
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

I tried to create an `Element`, add an `Attribute` to it and then add the `Element` as child to the `Capabilities`. But this generates wrong stuff. For example:

PowerShell #1:

```
$newElement = $manifest.Package.Capabilities.AppendChild($manifest.CreateElement("rescap:Capability"))
$newElement.SetAttribute(“Name”,”perceptionSensorsExperimental”)
```

Generates #1:

```
<Package>
  <Capabilities>
    <uap2:Capability Name="spatialPerception" />
    <Capability Name="perceptionSensorsExperimental" xmlns="" />
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

How can I create the mentioned line, consisting of `rescap:Capability` and the attribute `Name="perceptionSensorsExperimental"`?

**--Edit**
Initial `Package.appxmanifest` document in its entirety:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
         xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
         xmlns:uap2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/2"
         xmlns:uap3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/3"
         xmlns:uap4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/4"
         xmlns:iot="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/iot/windows10"
         xmlns:mobile="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/mobile/windows10"
         ignorableNamespaces="uap uap2 uap3 uap4 mp mobile iot rescap"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
         xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities">
  <Identity Name="XXXX" Publisher="CN=XXXX" Version="1.0.0.0" />
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>XXXX</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>XXXXX</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>
  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.10240.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.22621.0" />
  </Dependencies>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate" />
  </Resources>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="XXXX.App">
      <uap:VisualElements DisplayName="XXXXX" Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png" Description="XXXX" BackgroundColor="transparent">
        <uap:DefaultTile ShortName="XXXX" Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png" />
        <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF" />
        <uap:InitialRotationPreference>
          <uap:Rotation Preference="landscape" />
          <uap:Rotation Preference="landscapeFlipped" />
          <uap:Rotation Preference="portrait" />
          <uap:Rotation Preference="portraitFlipped" />
        </uap:InitialRotationPreference>
      </uap:VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
    <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
    <uap:Capability Name="sharedUserCertificates" />
    <uap2:Capability Name="spatialPerception" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="webcam" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="microphone" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="gazeinput" />
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

Comment: Are you sure that's what you have? Namespace declarations for the `uap2` prefix seem to be missing from the initial document...

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Sorry, I only removed that here so that it looks more readable. I guess I'd better add it after all, since it causes confusion.

Comment: Yes, please post the whole input document exactly as-is :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I added the link to my appxmanifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `.CreateElement()` to create the new node, there is a third parameter you can give it, which is the url taken from the `xmlns:rescap` declaration

By using that, things should work as wanted:

```
# the full path and filename
$file = 'D:\Test\Package.appxmanifest'
# load the xml file. This way, you are ensured to get the file encoding correct
$xml = [System.Xml.XmlDocument]::new()
$xml.Load($file)

# use the url from the `xmlns:rescap` declaration
$nsUri   = $xml.DocumentElement.GetNamespaceOfPrefix('rescap')
$newNode = $xml.CreateElement("rescap", "Capability", $nsUri)
$newNode.SetAttribute("Name","perceptionSensorsExperimental")
[void]$xml.Package.Capabilities.AppendChild($newNode)

$xml.Save($file)
```

Result (shortened)

```
. . .
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
    <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
    <uap:Capability Name="sharedUserCertificates" />
    <uap2:Capability Name="spatialPerception" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="webcam" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="microphone" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="gazeinput" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="perceptionSensorsExperimental" />
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Xml Linq :

```
using assembly System 
using assembly System.Linq
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

$inputFilename = "c:\temp\test.xml"
$outputFilename = "c:\temp\test1.xml"
$xDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)
$root = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]$xDoc.Root
#Write-Host "root = " $root
$ns = [System.Xml.Linq.XNamespace]$root.GetDefaultNamespace()
$nsUap2 = [System.Xml.Linq.XNamespace]$root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("uap2")
$Capabilities = $xDoc.Descendants($ns + "Capabilities")
$Capability = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::First($Capabilities)

$newElement = New-Object System.Xml.Linq.XElement($nsUap2 + "Capability")
$newElement.SetAttributeValue("Name", 'perceptionSensorsExperimental')
$Capability.Add($newElement)
Write-Host $xDoc
$xDoc.Save($outputFilename)
```